# How to group DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

My current DataGridView looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to achieve that each (column) "Fachanwendung" is grouping the data by displaying it as a Header. I've tried it with the DataGridViewGrouper like here: https://10tec.com/articles/datagridview-grouping-two-recipes.aspx

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/995958/DataGridViewGrouper

Unfortunately, my DataSource and DataMembers are either null or "". Therefore I can't call it like this:

```
DataGridViewGrouper grouper = new DataGridViewGrouper(dataGridView);
grouper.SetGroupOn("Fachanwendung");
//grouper.SetGroupOn(this.dataGridView.Columns["fachanwendung"]);
```

Is there any other way to display (at least a text) over a specific row?

Comment: Why don't use group/Pivot in the sql database and then show the data accordingly?

Comment: I have a Dictionary, where the Data is grouped: `public Dictionary<string, List<ElementInfo>> groupedItems`.
The key is the ID of the fachanwendung. Every fachanwendung has a list of items. I'd like to group the datagridview by showing the fachanwendung as a header and the list as the datagridview. The column "fachanwendung" shouldn't appear at all (= should appear as a header).

Comment: The screenshot matches to what you need, I think I missed something can you please explain the difference between the screen you attached and your requirement?

Comment: "archiMap" and "Event Management System" shouldn't be a column, they should be a row, which goes over every column. This means there's just one row, which spans all columns and its content is "archiMap". Underneath it are the 2 rows "Java.." and "Microsoft..".
Then there's a new row "Event Management System", which groups the other 3 elements.

Comment: It should look like this: https://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/531606/image2.png
"Name" should be in my example "Fachanwendung"

Comment: You are creating a Pivot Table (like in Excel).  Need to see sample of input dictionary to help.

Comment: @jdweng Input is a `Dictionary<string, List<Element>> fachanwendungenWithElements;`. The string is the "Fachanwendung" and the List is the list of elements on the right side of this string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a DataTable which you can use as the DatSource of the DGV.  See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication98
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Element> elements = new List<Element>() {
                new Element() {  Fachanwendung = "archiMap", Elementtyp = "Herstellerproduktversion", Elementname = "Java SE JRE 8", Date = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2017"), Quantity = 10},
                new Element() {  Fachanwendung = "archiMap", Elementtyp = "Herstellerproduktversion", Elementname = "Microsoft Window Server 2012 Standard", Date = DateTime.Parse("3/1/2017"), Quantity = 12},
                new Element() {  Fachanwendung = "Event Management System", Elementtyp = "Herstellerproduktversion", Elementname = "Apache Toimcat 8.0", Date = DateTime.Parse("6/1/2018"), Quantity = 5},
                new Element() {  Fachanwendung = "Event Management System", Elementtyp = "Herstellerproduktversion", Elementname = "Oracle Java JDK 7", Date = DateTime.Parse("12/1/2018"), Quantity = 5},
                new Element() {  Fachanwendung = "Event Management System", Elementtyp = "Herstellerproduktversion", Elementname = "Oracle Java JDK 8", Date = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2019"), Quantity = 5}
            };

            Dictionary<string, List<Element>> dict = elements.GroupBy(x => x.Fachanwendung, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Fachanwendung", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Elementtyp", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Elementname", typeof(string));

            //add quarters
            DateTime minDate = dict.SelectMany(x =>  x.Value.Select(y => y.Date)).Min(x => x.Date);
            DateTime maxDate = dict.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Select(y => y.Date)).Max(x => x.Date);

            DateTime startQuarter = new DateTime(minDate.Year, ((minDate.Month - 1) % 3) + 1, 1);
            DateTime endQuarter = new DateTime(maxDate.Year, ((maxDate.Month - 1) % 3) + 1, 1);

            for (DateTime date = startQuarter; date <= endQuarter; date = date.AddMonths(3))
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(date.Year.ToString() + " Q" + (((date.Month - 1)/ 3) + 1).ToString(), typeof(int));
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<Element>> rows in dict)
            {
                var groups = dict[rows.Key].GroupBy(x => new { Elementtyp = x.Elementtyp, Elementname = x.Elementname, Date = new DateTime(x.Date.Year, ((x.Date.Month - 1) % 3) + 1, 1) }).ToList();
                foreach (var group in groups)
                {
                    DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                    newRow["Fachanwendung"] = rows.Key;
                    newRow["Elementtyp"] = group.Key.Elementtyp;
                    newRow["Elementname"] = group.Key.Elementname;
                    string quarter = group.Key.Date.Year.ToString() + " Q" + (((group.Key.Date.Month - 1) / 3) + 1).ToString();
                    int total = group.Sum(x => x.Quantity);
                    newRow[quarter] = total;
                }

            }

        }
    }
    public class Element
    {
        public string Fachanwendung { get; set; }
        public string Elementtyp { get; set; }
        public string Elementname { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got your requirement now basically you want to have a block for each group in the data grid view. This can be resolved using Nested grid view. Here is very good link which you can use https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/848637/Nested-DataGridView-in-windows-forms-csharp

Also if you don't want expand collapse functionality you can easily remove that. Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: Is it also somehow possible to build this for a DataGridView and in XAML/C#?

Comment: @Rudi I have updated my answer and provided you a good link for Nested Data Grid View. Let me know if this helps.